# Does Eperi Gateway for Databases still exist?

Tags: mariadb, transparent-data-encryption

Is Eperi Gateway for Databases still offered and maintained?

We are interested in implementing TDE (transparent data encryption) on our MariaDB servers in order to have encryption of data at rest. MariaDB's documentation https://mariadb.com/kb/en/eperi-key-management-encryption-plugin/ indicates that key management for TDE is available using a plugin they provide to Eperi Gateway for Databases. I can't find the latter on Eperi's website, or find an authoritative source at Eperi via Googling, and they haven't responded to a query about it from a week ago. When I contacted MariaDB via chat they indicated that it was no longer available, but they had a paid product that would provide key management for TDE.

We would prefer not to have to migrate from MariaDB to Percona, though Percona's TDE that relies on Hashicorp Vault looks like a suitable combination.

Comment: MariaDB 10.9 community edition will have support for HashiCorp Vault, see [MDEV-19281](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19281). You may be able to try out this feature in a forthcoming MariaDB 10.9 preview release or beta release, see [MariaDB.org downloads](https://mariadb.org/download). MariaDB enterprise edition already [has support for HashiCorp Vault](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-platform-x5-includes-support-for-hashicorp-vault-kms/).

Comment: Thanks, @dbdemon. It would very much suit our purposes if MariaDB enterprise edition support for HashiCorp Vault was release in the MariaDB Community Edition. While we tend not to using bleeding edge in production, we'll test this and implement when it goes GA. Thanks!